# Force Language Path Prefix For Default Language

Tags: 7, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual site configured to use `path prefix` for URL language detection.

When no prefix is used in the URL, the default language is assumed. How can I change this behavior?

I want the site to return content only when a language prefix is set in the URL, otherwise return a "page not found" error.

**Reasoning behind this functionality:**

- Preventing duplicate content in search engines
- Keeping everything well organized (under language prefixes)
- Avoiding users to be able to view content without a language prefix and thus potentially link to it (loosing link juice)

*Edit: added reasoning.*

Comment: Mind explaning why you want that?

Comment: The client wants it this way :)

Comment: Yeah, clients frequently wants magic to happen as well ;) This is just my personal opinion, but I don't consider that a very motivating reason to answer.

Comment: I have to agree with you, my reasoning is not very motivating (even for me). Meantime the client has reconsidered this. Though, there are some good reasons why someone would want such functionality, which I will add to the question later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I found was using the [Global Redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module with the default options. It redirects all URLs without a language prefix to the correct URL with the default language prefix contained.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure it from (admin/config/regional/language/edit/en) if English language is the default and change (‏Path prefix language code) field from empty to en for example

Comment: I already use this, but I can still access the site without any prefix. I need the site to be accessible exclusively using a language prefix.

Answer (score -1):

@ovi: Next to the language list tab, there is another tab - "Detection and selection".
URL: admin/config/regional/language/configure
Go to this page and enable detection method - URL.
Save settings. It should work now. It worked for me without having additional modules.