# Multilingual site, always use language path prefix (no bare URLs)

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n

I have a Drupal 8 site with two languages, Japanese (default language) and English.

By default, the default language pages are available at both `/` and `/ja`.

For example, `/about` and `/ja/about` both go to the Japanese "about" page.

I want to get Drupal to force the path prefix so that the URL is always shown as `/ja/about` and never just `/about`.

**Interface text language detection** settings

- URL (path prefix, english: en, Japanese: ja)
- Selected language (Japanese)

How can I do this?

**For Drupal 7:** [see this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/28126/force-language-path-prefix-for-default-language)

Comment: The accepted answer of the linked question is still correct, only that Global Redirect is deprecated and you should use Redirect, see the module description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Select "English" as the default language and save
2. Select "Japanese", again, as the default language and save

This way, you will force Drupal to prefix the URL's by the language id, even for the default language.

Comment: How is it even _supposed_ to work? It doesn't seem to work on `8.9.3`.

Answer (score 6):

Here the steps:

1. Install [Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/redirect) module.
2. Enable the module `/admin/modules`
3. Go to admin page `/admin/config/search/redirect/settings`.
4. Ensure **Enforce clean and canonical URLs** is checked.

Comment: This did the trick. Thanks Patrick Kenny.

Answer (score 2):

Prefix - suffix configuration is moved to the URL language detections settings at Drupal 8
Please, use this path to edit suffixes for each language:

```
admin/config/regional/language/detection/url
```

And dont forget to move up URL detection rule